# Recursively loading doctests in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, python-unittest, doctest

I'm trying to test a python module, which has a separate test module:

```
my_module/
test/
setup.py
```

The `test` module has unittests for `my_module`, but it also needs to load `doctests` from `my_module`. To this end, I have the following `load_tests` function, located in `test/__init__.py`:

```
import my_module

def load_tests(loader, tests, pattern):
    # Load the unit tests from `test`
    unittests = loader.discover(start_dir=os.path.dirname(__file__), pattern=pattern)
    # Load the doctests from `my_module`
    doctests = doctest.DocTestSuite(my_module)

    tests.addTests(unittests)
    tests.addTests(doctests)
    return tests
```

However, this fails with the error:

```
Error
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I load all the doctests from `my_module` in this test loader?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, in my example it was actually the `unittest` loader that was failing, making me think it was a fault in `doctest`.

However, to answer the question in the title, you can recursively run doctests like this:

```
import doctest
import pkgutil
import my_module

def load_tests(loader, tests, pattern):
    for importer, name, ispkg in pkgutil.walk_packages(my_module.__path__, my_module.__name__ + '.'):
        tests.addTests(doctest.DocTestSuite(name))
    return tests
```